# Trying to Yarn add a private Github repo and get 'couldn't find the binary git' error

Tags: github, homebrew, yarnpkg

I have a really simple repo in GitHub (/Hooks/), currently containing just 1 file, a simple Hooks.ts typescript file. On my local machine, in my Workspace, I've created a project folder and I can yarn add normal repositories like `yarn add fuse.js` but I wanted to yarn add my private repo `yarn add Hooks` using this format `yarn add git+ssh//git@github.com:OrganisationName/Hooks.git` but I just get Error: couldn't find the binary git'. I have permissions to the Hooks repo because I can push/pull from it. I'm on OSX Mojave (10.14.16) and installed Yarn via brew. My yarn version (yarn -v) is 1.22.10. This is the latest brew will install after running `brew upgrade yarn`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error "couldn't find the binary git" is related with not having installed git where the installation is made, Are you running these. commands inside a container?
you might as well be installing openssh, is necessary too.

**for example in an alpine container**

```
apk add --no-cache git openssh
yarn install
```

If, just in case, you don't want to access to the repo trough SSH, you can access trough https+deploy-token, heres a gitlab example:

```
git+https://<token-name>:<token>@gitlab.com/Username/Repository#<branch|tag>
```